# VB.net Finding First and Last uppercase letter

Tags: vb.net, uppercase

For Example :
String = Visual BasiC
output = V C

I have tried searching everywhere but found none, is it possible for vb.net to do this one?

Comment: [Research Regex (Regular Expressions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx). As this should be able to do it

Comment: The [Char.IsUpper Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper(v=vs.110).aspx) is a simple test to perform. Did you intend to include the space in the output?

Comment: Please read [ask]  and take the [tour].  This is not a tutorial site and we are not here to do your homework for you

Answer (score 2):

The following code iterates forward through the string until it finds a capital letter, adds that to the result and exits the first loop. It then iterates backwards through the string until it finds a capital letter, adds it to the result and exits the loop. Finally, it returns the result to the calling code.

I suspect that this is a school/college assignment, so I would suggest that you read [Open letter to Students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

```
Private Function FirstAndLastCapitalLetter(s As String) As String
    Dim result As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To s.Length - 1
        If s.Substring(i, 1) = s.Substring(i, 1).ToUpper Then
            result = result & s.Substring(i, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    For i As Integer = s.Length - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If s.Substring(i, 1) = s.Substring(i, 1).ToUpper Then
            result = result & s.Substring(i, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Using `.ToUpper()` does not always do what you expect. Jon Skeet gives a really good talk which includes the problem: [Back to basics: the mess we'vw made of our fundamental data types](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1264&v=l3nPJ-yK-LU). That link starts some way in - I recommend watching the whole thing :)

Comment: Now I understand why NodaTime took so long!

Comment: While I'm sure this works, you're creating a lot of strings!  Your `If` statement alone creates 3 separate strings.  You can access a character in a string using `s(i)` and use the `Char.IsUpper` method to determine if it upper case.